# Does anyone know how I can set the safe-volume for headphone in KDE?

Tags: sound, kde, headphones, volume-control

I dont even know if this is the right term "safe-volume"....but I have just changed to KDE and before I used MATE. In MATE when I plugged in my earphones.....the system immediately set the volume to, more or less, 60%. Which was great to protect my ears from loud noise if I previously had the volume set to 100%.

Is there a way to set this in KDE?

UPDATE. I have found a solution. veromix widget in KDE can be set for headphones.

Answer (score -1):

Alsa is the underlying control for all of the sound on your computer.

The `alsamixer` command can adjust all of the "gains" on each of the sound devices. It's a command line command and it will present a visual picture.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is that same thing that is being asked. If you reduce the headphone setting in `alsamixer`, you cannot use the volume keys to reset it to maximum volume. However, if the system modifies the master volume instead (e.g. to 60%), then you can easily use the volume settings to reset it to 100%. I think the OP is talking about a dynamic setting rather than static. (But I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Sparhawk yes, that's what I mean. I wanna be able to use 100% of the volume on earphones and speakers too. But I want the system to set the earphone volume to 60% as soon as an earphone or headphone is detected. This way protecting my ears. Is there a way to do this?